# Диамант или адамант?

Tags: грамотная-речь

У бриллианта есть другое название - диамант. Насколько я знаю, оно устаревшее, либо употребляется, когда фразе хотят придать несколько высокопарный оттенок.
Но иногда я встречаю форму "адамант". Она похожа на первую, но все-таки произносится иначе. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильнее: "диамант" или "адамант"? И откуда взялись разночтения в названии камня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Диамант" – позднелатинское слово, видоизменённое греческое "ἀδάμας" ("адамас"). Видимо, слова пришли в русский язык разными путями, потому существовали параллельно. "Диамант", насколько я понял, из французского, а второе — из греческого через церковно-славянский. В иносказательном смысле более предпочтительным является "адамант".

Answer (score 2):

Знакомый ювелир как-то говорил мне, что диамант (diamond) и адамант (adamant) - это названия разных форм огранки драг. камней (не только алмазов, но и сапфиров и проч.).

Ссылок найти не могу, так что остается верить только на слово. :)

Comment:  Это, возможно, "междусобойчик" ювелиров, который даже словари не отражают.